# can I use an XSLT function to duplicate adding the xsl:attribute statements in similar templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a series of templates which are processing various type of mapping elements differently. But, I want a similar set of attributes to be added to the generated element. Is there a way to do this with an XSLT function, or is there another recommended way?

Here is an example of a mapping template, this one is for ones that have no source values. Those three attributes that are added to the generated element, I don't want to duplicate in each mapping template. Is there a way to avoid doing that?

```
<xsl:template match="mapping[source/not(*)]">
  <xsl:element name="{{destination/attribute/text()}}" namespace="{{destination/attribute/@namespace}}">
    <xsl:attribute name="mapping-key"><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="override"><xsl:value-of select="(@override, 'false')[1]"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="single-value"><xsl:value-of select="(@single-value, 'false')[1]"/></xsl:attribute>

    <!-- add custom stuff to the element specific to this template -->
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks,

-tj

Comment: See `<xsl:attributes/>` or possibly `<xsl:attribute-set/>`, can't remember which it is called and don't have references handy.

Comment: You can also use a common template with `xsl:next-match` - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-next-match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `xsl:attribute-set` here, to allow you to re-use groups of attributes in different places.

For example, see this XSLT (I removed the `namespace` creation for brevity)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:attribute-set name="attrSet">
    <xsl:attribute name="mapping-key" select="generate-id(.)"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="override" select="(@override, 'false')[1]"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="single-value" select="(@single-value, 'false')[1]"/>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:template match="mapping[source/not(*)]">
  <xsl:element name="{destination/attribute/text()}" use-attribute-sets="attrSet">
    <!-- add custom stuff to the element specific to this template -->
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, I have used the slightly simplified format for creating attributes (with `select` on the `xsl:attribute` statement) as available in XSLT 2.0.

Also, I note, you used double-curly braces in creating the element names `{{destination/attribute/text()}}"`, where it should only be single, but I am guessing you may be doing some text pre-processing of the XSLT before using it, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @tim-c. I am actually generating the XSLT in XQuery, hence the double curly braces. I didn't notice it when I tool the snippet out. This suggestion should work perfectly.